# how to convert hex value to decimal value of pixel?

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel

int seed=0X0DEC0DED value is assigned to one of the pixels of my cover image.
so is it possible to initialized hex value as seed value for pixel?

Comment: did you mean as int value?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function like this

```
public static int hex2Decimal(String s) {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int d = digits.indexOf(c);
            val = 16*val + d;
        }
        return val;
 }
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt(String s,int radix);
```

or

Integer seed = 0X0DEC0DED;